# Delete entire subgraph from a start node - subgraph is a connected component

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete a whole subgraph, using the following query:

```
match 
(n:StartNode {id:'id1'})-[r*1..6]-(m) 
foreach(rel in r|delete rel) with n, collect(distinct m) as del_nodes2
foreach(node in del_nodes2|delete node);
```

All components in the subgraph are connected. The start node does exist. The maximum chain length is 6. However, i am getting the following error:

```
javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException: Failed to commit transaction Transaction(6, owner:"qtp1905632138-213")[STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION,Resources=1], transaction rolled back ---> javax.transaction.xa.XAException
```

Answer (score 3):

2 suggestions:

1. Specify relationship directionality in your `MATCH` clause, or else you could end up deleting not just the descendants of your start node, but all its *ancestors* as well! Also, this may be why your deletion is failing -- some of the ancestor nodes may have other relationships that your query does not try to delete.
2. You should be able to simplify you query.

Try this:

```
MATCH (:StartNode {id:'id1'})-[r*1..6]->(m)
FOREACH(rel in r | DELETE rel)
DELETE m;
```